# Unexpected NullPointerException with Safe Navigation operator

Tags: apex, safe-navigation-operator

We are seeing an intermittent failure from an integration that creates Tasks; it is throwing a NullPointerException in our Task Trigger handler.

> TaskTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Here is the relevant section of code:

```
for (Task task : newTasks) {
    if (task.WhatId?.getSobjectType() == Opportunity.SObjectType) {
        opportunitiesForScoring.add(task.WhatId);
    }
}
```

`newTasks` is just `Trigger.new`, passed in from the trigger, after update.  The exception occurs on the second line above - the `if` statement.  In that line, `task` can never be null, as `Trigger.new` will never contain a null.  If `task.WhatId` is null, then `task.WhatId?.getSobjectType()` just evaluates to `null`, and `if (null == Opportunity.SObjectType)` should work just fine.  But I have double checked the line number and code in Production, and that is the line causing the exception.

As a preemptive work-around, I've added an extra null check before the `if` statement (`if (task?.WhatId == null) continue;`), which should be deployed to production soon, but I've been unable to come up with a reproduction case in sandbox, so I'll only know if the change works if we stop seeing intermittent errors.  Even if this resolves the issue, I'd like to understand why this exception occurs.

Comment: What is the exact exception? Attempt to de-reference a null object or argument cannot be null? Are you 100% sure the method is not executed in before/after delete context?

Comment: @user254875486 Added the exact exception text, which answers both of your questions.  "attempt to de-reference", occurring in AfterUpdate.

Comment: Thanks for the update. You're getting the exception on the line with the for loop right? That must mean that `newTasks` is somehow null. Can you reliably reproduce the error on production?

Comment: @user254875486 No. As stated in the question, the error occurs on the `if` line, not on the `for` line.  I have checked the line number multiple times in the production org where the error occurs.  Also, newTasks is the method param and it's just being passed `Trigger.new`, so it really cannot be null in AfterUpdate context.

Comment: Right, I'm sorry, I misread the question :) Can you check if you have a variable named `opportunity` somewhere above this logic which might not be initialised? I noticed you're using `task` as a variable name for the task. Apex is not case sensitive, so if there is a variable called `opportunity` in the same scope, and it's uninitialised, the right hand side of the check will attempt to call `getSObjectType()` on that null-instance instead of on the SObject. As a rule, I tend to prevent using SObject types as variable names.

Comment: @user254875486 No, there is not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147183/discussion-between-user254875486-and-jason-clark).